# While loop to test if files with a given pattern exist in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to check with a file loop like this, if files with a given pattern exist:

```
while [ ! -f "/tmp/?????-Stock.txt" ]
do
  sleep 2
done
```

If more files like 12aaa-Stock.txt, 34aaa-Stock.txt are present I have a message error like  binary operator expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by using a for-loop, e.g,.

```
DONE=no
while [ "$DONE" = no ]
do
    for name in /tmp/?????-Stock.txt
    do
        if [ -f "$name" ]
        then
             DONE=yes
             break
        fi
    done
    [ "$DONE" = no ] && sleep 2
done
```

As long as there are no files found, the for-loop has one item to process (the unmatched pattern).  If multiple files are found, the for-loop exits immediately on the first match.

[@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) notes that I could have used `break 2` (old habits die hard).  That would look like this:

```
while :
do
    for name in /tmp/?????-Stock.txt
    do
        [ -f "$name" ] && break 2
    done
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: You can use `break 2` to exit both the `for` loop and the `while` loop. This lets you get rid of the `DONE` variable altogether by using `while : ; do` as an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array to get expanded globs first and then check for # of elements:

```
shopt -s nullglob

while arr=(/tmp/?????-Stock.txt); [[ ${#arr[@]} -eq 0 ]]; do
   sleep 2
done
```

`shopt -s nullglob` is required to suppress glob pattern when there is no matching file for given glob pattern.